# Reload Braintree Drop-In UI After Payment Method Delete

Tags: javascript, braintree

When I perform, `this.gateway.paymentMethod.delete(response.paymentMethod.token);`, is there any way to reload the Drop-In UI to explicitly show the user that their payment method has been deleted? In other words, the payment method is removed from the list of payment methods within the Drop-In UI.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can reload the Drop-in UI by using the [`teardown`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html#teardown) method on the Drop-in instance, followed by a subsequent [`braintree.dropin.create()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3#client-side-implementation) call. The `teardown` method will cleanly remove everything setup by a `dropin.create` call. You can use the method similarly to this:

```
instance.teardown(function (teardownErr) {
  if (teardownErr) {
    console.error('Could not tear down Drop-in UI!');
  } else {
    console.info('Drop-in UI has been torn down!');
  }
});
```

Once the Drop-in is torn down, you can then call `braintree.dropin.create()` again to setup the Drop-in to display the customer's accurate stored payment methods.

While slightly different implementation, there is an example of the `teardown` method in [this tutorial](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/tutorial#add-the-drop-in-ui-markup).

**UPDATE:** A newer version of the Drop-in UI was just released that allows customers to delete their payment methods from within the Drop-in. You can use this by upgrading to the latest version of the [Drop-in (v1.12.0)](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1120).

Once you've upgraded, set [`vaultManager`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/module-braintree-web-drop-in.html#.create) to `true` within your `braintree.dropin.create()` call, similar to this:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION',
  container: '#dropin-container',
  vaultManager: true
}, callback);
```